# ASP.NET program fine for 30 mins then crashes

Tags: asp.net

My ASP.NET program works fine for 30 mins (approx) then crashes with the generic status code 500. I've reviewed my code and can't seem to figure out what the problem could be. The program is running under II6 and I'm using .Net 2.0. Could this be an application pool issue?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it can be an application pool issue.

Answer (score 1):

There should be some helpful information in the Application Event Log.  Without more detail it would be tough to offer any more than advice other than "keep looking".

Answer (score 1):

`Error 500` explains that something gone wrong at the `server side`, this is all it knows

Following post wiil help. It addresses IIS 5.1 but process is identical for IIS 6.0

- [**Resolving Http 500 Server Errors in
  ASP.Net**](http://timstall.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/resolving_http_500_server_errors_in_aspnet_and_iis_51.htm)